# Delphi XE2 - Nested Class functions don't compile

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am upgrading some legacy 3rd party components from Delphi 6 source up to XE2.

The 3rd party source has nested class function within a class procedure.  Mock up exact working copy which will fail:

```
type
  TMyClass1 = class
  public
    class procedure DoSomething;
  end;

{ TMyClass1 }

class procedure TMyClass1.DoSomething;
  class function DoSomethingelse: boolean;
  begin
    result := false;
  end;
begin

end;
```

trying to compile this gives an error about doSomethingelse being an undeclared identifier.  Now I can (presumably) resolve this by pulling the nested function out to the same level, but is there a compiler option that I can set to prevent this?  Is this something which has recently changed?  Has anyone else come across this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps nested function should not have "class" word next to it. If you ant to pull it up - pull it with "class" keyword and add to private section.

Comment: Some of the 3rd party code in my codebase hit this issue when I moved to XE2. Best solution is to remove the class on the inner. I bet this change is at XE2 and the code above works for all earlier versions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this code fails in Delphi XE too, so the change was made in some version between Delphi 2007 and XE.

Comment: @RRUZ I encountered the issue when moving from 2010 to XE2 so I guess it was XE then. I assumed XE2 since that was where the more major upheaval took place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to compile your code in XE2 just remove the `class` Keyword of the `DoSomethingelse` definition, even if this code compile in older versions of delphi (I tested your code in Delphi 5, 7 and 2007) I don't see the point (or difference) of declare a embedded (inner) procedure or function with the `class` keyword.